# processingjs red() green() blue()

Tags: javascript, processing.js

I want to send a sting from processing js to javascript with the color to use in css.
so formatted like:
"rgb(255, 0, 0)"
(or whatever color values).

no matter what i try i get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function

I did several tests and it is always red(.... that is causing the error (and probably green and blue).

```
String getRowColor(int r) {
  if (r > rows || r < 0) {
    return null;
  } 
  else {
    color c= colors[r];
    String cStr = "rgb(";
    cStr += red(c)+", ";
    cStr += green(c)+", ";
    cStr += blue(c)+")";
    return cStr;
  }
}
```

Comment: You question says "Javascript", but you've tagged this "Java".  Which is it?

Comment: if java, use `StringBuffer` for concatenation.

Comment: Are there functions for red(c), green(c), and blue(c)?

Comment: I am not very familiar with processing.js but can you try `cStr = join(cStr,str(red(c)),", ");`

Comment: oops it's javascript. Most of the times i use java, my mistake.
For the rest both processingjs as processing have functions red(c) etc.

Comment: Are you sure `colors[]` contains actual color objects?

Comment: @Timothy Groote O this is a long time ago :)

Comment: I figured, but i don't think it's a dumb enough question to warrant -2 and no solution :)

Answer (score -1):

I think that:
`color c= colors[r];`
should be: `color c= color(r);`

Comment: The rest of the code implies that `colors` is an array of `Color`